# Converting Timedelta from a Pandas Dataframe to a seconds value

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I have a column in a `pandas.DataFrame` titled `Residuals` and it is in a `timedelta` format (`00:00:01.14611` for example). I have 47 of those listed values in the `Residuals` column and I need to convert them all back to just a seconds value (i.e. `1.14611`). I have tried `pd.to_numeric(df['Residual'].dt.seconds, downcast='integer')` but that has not worked out and a few other methods.

Any input would be greatly appreciated as I am incredibly new to using Python and pandas dataframes. Thanks

Comment: `df['Residual'].dt.total_seconds()` is what you want.

Comment: @nf95 Please check the dtype of the column again

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [time-delta objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) documentation. It is essentially a difference of two `datetime.date`/`datetime.datetime` objects.

This code snippet will easily explain how you wanna solve your question:

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>d1 = datetime.now()
>>>d2 = datetime.now()

>>>d2-d1
datetime.timedelta(0, 8, 14319) 
>>>(d2-d1).total_seconds() 
8.014319
```

You should try doing `df["Residual"].dt.total_seconds()`

EDIT:

```
df['Residual'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method gives me an attribute errors.  


AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @nf95 please use the updated solution. Please upvote if it helped

Comment: it is still giving me an attribute error in regards to the .total_seconds() function. "Series object has no attribute"

Comment: @nf95 I have added another solution with the use of a lambda expression

Comment: Seems you don’t actually have a Series of timedelta. Check the dtype

Comment: `df['Residual'].dt.total_seconds()`- [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) ?